# Valid H1B visa but not stamped. Want to attend a conference in Spain. Am I eligible to get schengen visa and re-enter US?

Tags: visas, usa, spain

I have a valid H1B visa though not stamped yet as I have not traveled to India since then. I got an invitation to speak at a conference in Spain next year. Am I eligible to get a schengen business visa? Is so, after conference I am aftraid I cannot re-enter US without stamping? Can I get it done in Spain or do I have to travel all the way to India, get it stamped and then enter US? Please advise?

Thanks much

Comment: I do not know whether you can get a Schengen visa, but you can certainly get a new H-1B visa in Spain.  People often travel to Mexico or Canada to do so, as well.

Comment: Do you mean you have a valid I-797? You don't have a valid visa until it is in your passport.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the other option is that it means "valid H-1B status": people often use "visa" when they mean "status" in the US.

Comment: @phoog It's very important to be clear when talking about visas, immigration and residence. Being confused or using the wrong terminology can lead to making mistakes and even possibly jeopardize one's status.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I agree, but if you've been reading anything about immigration law as an issue in US politics these days, there's lots of talk of people "overstaying their visas."  That sort of thing doesn't help.